# Where does Vagrant install plugins on Windows?

Tags: vagrant

I'm looking to add some features to an opensource Vagrant plugin which was installed with `vagrant plugin install`. I cannot, however, find where it has put those files on Windows.

Where does Vagrant install plugin rb files?

Comment: Thanks to the person that voted down the question. It's usually customary to put a comment on it explaining why.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I found these at `C:\Users\<username>\.vagrant.d\gems\gems`

Answer (score 2):

At the risk of a downvote I google searched for the location on Linux and this thread came up first so I'll throw in the info that I have. For Ubuntu 16.04.1 I found locally installed vagrant plugins at:

`/home/username/.vagrant.d/gems/gems`